# Running a .Net 4.0 website beneath a 2.0 site

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, .net-4.0, application-pool

We're running our default website in a .Net 2.0 app pool.  We've since created a new app beneath it, running in an ASP 4.0 (integrated) app pool.  We've been getting messages about the system.web.extensions section group in the 4.0 app, among others.  These messages go away when we remove that section from the parent app's web.config file, but we'd rather not do that.  We're using IIS 7.

Is there guidance or best practices for running a 4.0 site as an app beneath an earlier version of .Net?  There seem to be a fair number of conflicts with the parent's web.config and I'm not sure how best to minimize them.

Comment: Would probably save yourself future headaches by upgrading the parent website to 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot (or do not want to) convert the main site so everything is the same .NET version then what you'll have to do is run them out of different application pools.

Have the 4.0 application running out of an application pool that is running in 4.0 mode.
Have the 2.0 application running out of an application pool that is running in 2.0 mode.

(Note, you have to be careful about any dependencies of the apps talking to each other)